# yocto build hostname not set

Tags: shell, hostname, yocto, bitbake

In my current yocto build, no hostname is set by default. This is strange, since within meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb do_install the hostname is set (if not an empty string):

```
if [ "${hostname}" ]; then
    echo ${hostname} > ${D}${sysconfdir}/hostname
fi
```

A few lines above the hostname is set to the Machine name:

```
hostname = "${MACHINE}"
```

Which is transformed to (within run.do_install):

```
if [ "" ]; then
    echo  > /my-path/etc/hostname
fi
```

Therefore the hostname seems to be not set?
The MACHINE VARIABLE is set of cause and even if i set the hostname to a fixed string, the problem persists:

```
hostname = "foo"
```

The recipe is executed by bitbake for sure and the only way to make it set the hostname is by patching like below, which is awful of cause...

```
echo "foo" > ${D}${sysconfdir}/hostname
```

I am pretty sure that I am missing something obvious here, but I am not able to track the problem down.

Here is the link to the file I am talking about
http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb?h=krogoth

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Never mind...

I found the line of code where I unset the hostname barried deep within one of my own recipes.

Comment: classic stack overflow answer